# Detect if my mic is muted in a call or meeting on MS Teams

Tags: api, microsoft-teams

Is there an API or something similar for MS Teams that tells if my microphone in a current call is muted or not?
I want to build an external light (green / red) showing whether my mic is muted or not. Probably I will use an ESP32 module for that

I have a Plantronics headset that has a led light indicating when it is muted on Teams, so I believe that there is an API for that...

I found this similar solution but it's a button to mute and, consequently, when press it, the light will change. But I want something just to detect the mute. - https://www.instructables.com/Microsoft-Teams-Mute-Button/

I couldn't find anything on internet about this..

Thanks for your attention!